# How can I run different experiments for the same network from the same .ini file?

Tags: networking, network-programming, omnet++, traffic-simulation, event-simulation

I am simulating a datacenter topology in omnet++. I have a network called **Test** with different parameters. So, I need to run two experiments for this network.

```
[Net]
network = Test
*.fwdAlgorithm = "sp"

[Net]
network = Test
*.fwdAlgorithm = "ksp"
```

So I need to run experiments with different algorithms. However, it is giving me duplicate key. I am not able to do it in this way. Any idea to make this happen ? your help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In `omnetpp.ini` set the following content:

```
[Net]
network = Test
*.fwdAlgorithm = ${"sp", "ksp"}
```

Then during starting a simulation you may choose desired configuration:

[image]

Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual, 10.4 Parameter Studies](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:config-sim:parameter-studies)